# Show random questions from a plist

Tags: iphone, ios, random, plist

I have a plist full of questions and answers (with the specified question) that show on an interface but I want to show the questions at random. See code I tried below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (questions && configDictionary) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [questions count]; ++i) { int r = (random() % [questions count]); [questions exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:r]; }

        [questionLabel setText:[[questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestonIndex] objectForKey:@"question"]];
        NSArray *answers = [[questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestonIndex] objectForKey:@"answers"];
        [answerLabel0 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:0]];
        [answerLabel1 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:1]];
        [answerLabel2 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:2]];
        [answerLabel3 setText:[answers objectAtIndex:3]];
        [pointsPerAnswerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%d points", [[configDictionary objectForKey:kPointsPerCorrectAnswer] intValue]]];
        [currentQuestionNumberLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"question %d", currentQuestonIndex+1]];
    }
}

Someone please help?
```

I get the warning " NSArray' may not respond to 'exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:" then it crashes after trying to run.

See my .h file below:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSDictionary *configDictionary;
    NSMutableArray *questions;
    int currentQuestonIndex;
    NSMutableArray *questionsCorrectlyAnswered;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int totalTimeLeft;
    int currentTimeLeft;

    BOOL saveTime;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *questions;
```

It still crashes.

My table view previous to view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    gameViewController = [[QuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizViewController"bundle:nil];
    [(QuizViewController*) gameViewController setMasterViewController:self];
    [(QuizViewController*) gameViewController setTitle:[[quizzes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"quizName"]];
    [(QuizViewController*) gameViewController setQuestions:[[quizzes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"questions"]];
    [gameViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: so what's not working about this?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I get the warning " NSArray' may not respond to 'exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:" then it crashes.

Comment: Search for Fisher Yates shuffle for a more mathematically sound shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Firstly, Are your sure your mutable Dictionary has the contents. Are your "questions" and "configDictionary" allocated and initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you set up "`questions`" (you don't show that in your code), you need to set it up as a "`NSMutableArray`" and not a immutable (non-changeable, non-exchangeable) "`NSArray`".

Comment: You have a spelling typo in there ("`NSMutableSArray`"), and you still haven't shown how "`questions`" is being loaded.

Comment: Ummm... even after all your edits, I still don't see where "`questions = __________`".  Where is it being loaded or set?

Comment: I have a table view previous to this view. So when you click an option in the table view it will display the question according to the option the user clicks.

Comment: I'm assuming you have set "`questions`" as a "`@property`".  Do your "`setQuestions`" with a parameter of "`[[quizzes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy]`".  Right now, you're only passing an immutable array.

Comment: I do see the new edited code and after trying that it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at it. Not an exact answer to your question but I did do something like this in the past. What I did was I had an array of comments that I wanted to randomize every time the app was launched. So this is how I did it.

```
NSMutableArray *funnyArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 @"Got Milk?",
                                 @"Got Food?",
                                 @"Life Is Like A Box of Chocolates", nil];

//Randmonize Array
    NSUInteger count = [funnyArray count];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
    {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [funnyArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

Now in your case you will randomize the questions only. But you want questions and answer pairs to be randomized together. That I am not sure how you can do. Perhaps the hard way will be to put a number next to your question in your array e.g. 1. Where is my milk? When you get that random str from the array question, you can strip out "1" and look for "1" in your answer array. I advise using nsmutablearrays as others have suggested. Just my 2 cents.